# Chrome 87.0.4280 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of null (skipped 229) ERROR (34.875 secs / 0 secs)

Tags: angular, google-chrome, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test my project angular 8.3.26 with jasmine 3.2.0 and karma but it show me this error:

```
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
DisconnectedClient disconnected from CONNECTED state (ping timeout)
```

and

```
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of null (skipped 229) ERROR (34.875 secs / 0 secs)
```

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

 module.exports = function (config) {
 config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/my-pro'),
        reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    captureTimeout: 60000, // it was already there
    browserDisconnectTolerance : 1,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 60000
   });
  };
```

I checked the solutions in the Stackoverflowbut the problem was not solved,

Do you have an opinion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with my computer resources.
Since the source map was active and put a lot of load on my computer. I disabled it with the following command to run the test:

```
ng test --source-map=false
```

This is also important. If your app is too big. To run the test, in the .spec.ts file that you are writing the test, use f before describe To focus only on this test file.

```
fdescribe('my-test', () => {....}
```